# Kernel of the map $R \to R[\alpha]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm working on a problem from Artin's Algebra, and I think it revealed a fundamental lack of understanding on the subject. The question is as follows:

Let $a$ be an element of a ring $R$, and let $R'=R[x]/(ax -1)$ obtained by adjoining an inverse of $a$ to $R$. Let $\alpha$ denote the residue of $x$ (the inverse of $a$ in $R$).

Part $a.)$ asked me to prove that any element $\beta \in R'$ is of the form $\alpha \cdot b$ for $b \in R$. This was straightforward and simple enough. Part $b.)$ is what's tripping me up. Part $b.)$ asks:

$b.)$ Prove that the kernel of the map $R \to R'$ is the set of elements $b$ of $R$ such that $a^nb=0$ for some $n>0$.

First off, I'm not sure what this map should even be. That seems important, but I have no idea where to begin.

My first idea was to define $\varphi: R' \to R$ given by $\alpha \mapsto a$. Then, using the statement from $a.)$, if $c=\alpha^kb \in \ker(\varphi)$ we have that:
$$\varphi(c)=\varphi(\alpha)^n\varphi(b)=a^nb=0$$
but I don't think that actually tells me anything about the map from $R \to R[\alpha]$? If anyone could give a hint of where to begin, or if anyone can see where my misunderstanding is, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The map $R\to R[x]/(ax-1)$ is of course $b\mapsto b+(ax-1)$.
- $b+(ax-1)=0+(ax-1)$ iff $b = f(x)(ax-1)$ for some $f\in R[x]$.

  Check that it means $$f(x)=-b\sum_{m=0}^n x^m a^m$$
  with $a^nb = 0$.
- ie. $b\in \ker(R\to R[x]/(ax-1))$ iff $\exists n\ge 0, b a^n =0$.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you very much!